# Is this a modulus of continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

Let $d \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that I have the following estimate:
$$|d(x)-d(y)|\leq C_T |x-y|+e^{-T}$$
for $C_T \to +\infty$ as $T \to \infty$.

Then if I define
$$\omega(|x|)=\lim_{T \to \infty} C_T |x|+e^{-T}$$
Then this is a modulus of continuity (i.e. $\omega(0)=0$ and it is subadditive), right?

The if I let $x \to y$ who guarantees that $\omega(|x-y|)\to 0$? I mean this is guaranteed if $T \to \infty$ sufficiently lower than $|x-y|\to0$, right?

But how do you guarantee it in general?

Comment: Isn't $\lim_{T \to \infty} C_T|x| + e^{-T} = \infty$ for all $|x| \not= 0$?

Comment: mm yes. How would you define a modulus of continuity then?

Comment: You should probably ask a separate question, as the answer to this one is no.